# Cassandra is not running

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed cassandra 2.2.12 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. when i go to /bin and run ./cassandr after that we are getting some error. Cassandra is not running, do we need to change in the Cassandra.yaml file?

The steps are given below:

```
#cd /tmp/
#sudo wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/2.2.12/apache- 
 cassandra- 
2.2.12-bin.tar.gz
#tar -xvf apache-cassandra-2.2.12-bin.tar.gz
#sudo rm -rf apache-cassandra-2.2.12-bin.tar.gz
#cd apache-cassandra-2.2.12/
#cd /bin/
#./cassandra
```

After running Cassandra, I am getting following **ERROR**:

```
owner@STS-YYC-UBUNTU:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.2.12/bin$ ./cassandra
owner@STS-YYC-UBUNTU:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.2.12/bin$ CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/AbstractNativeCell.compareTo (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/composites/AbstractSimpleCellNameType.compareUnsigned (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.2.12/conf/cassandra.yaml
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.2.12/conf/cassandra.yaml
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:118)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:149)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:133)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:507)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:642)
Caused by: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=rpc_port for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@5427c60c; For input string: "0.1.2.234"
 in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    ^

        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:333)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:141)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:127)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:475)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:111)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Cannot create property=rpc_port for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@5427c60c; For input string: "0.1.2.234"
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:299)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:189)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:331)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.1.2.234"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:479)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.createNumber(SafeConstructor.java:228)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.access$100(SafeConstructor.java:45)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlInt.construct(SafeConstructor.java:211)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructScalar.constructStandardJavaInstance(Constructor.java:459)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructScalar.construct(Constructor.java:365)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:296)
        ... 13 more
ERROR 04:44:58 Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.2.12/conf/cassandra.yaml
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:118) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:149) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:133) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:507) [apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:642) [apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=rpc_port for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@5427c60c; For input string: "0.1.2.234";  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    ^
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:333) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:141) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:127) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:475) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:111) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Cannot create property=rpc_port for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@5427c60c; For input string: "0.1.2.234"
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:299) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:189) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:331) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.1.2.234"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:479) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.createNumber(SafeConstructor.java:228) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.access$100(SafeConstructor.java:45) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlInt.construct(SafeConstructor.java:211) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructScalar.constructStandardJavaInstance(Constructor.java:459) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructScalar.construct(Constructor.java:365) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:296) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Kindly assist if anyone has idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: You are using an invalid IP address 0.1.2.234. https://serverfault.com/questions/300260/is-0-1-2-3-a-valid-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

You set `rpc_port` as `0.1.2.234` which cannot be converted into a port number so it threw a NumberFormatException.